# Limit currently handled messages in NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

Is there a way to limit the number of messages that are currently being handled by NServiceBus?
If there are 7 messages in the mq I want NServiceBus to handle only 4 messages simultaneously?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the MaximumConcurrencyLevel to 4 in the TransportConfig section:

https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/blob/f4c2c3032a4d4de2cc4e2f3039d1461ca97a1d56/src/NServiceBus.Core/Config/TransportConfig.cs#L12

This will make sure that max 4 messages can be processed at the same time